# How can i make this keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, keyboard

The bank app Abn Mobile Banking for the ipad had a nice login page.

how can i make something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fully customized. It doesn't use any built-in keyboard functionalities so you'll basically end up creating your own one in photoshop.

The easy way is creating separate buttons. On touch, you add the value to an array which you eventually combine to a string (`componentsJoinedByString:`).

The hard way is creating one view with your own touch events. It's way faster, uses less memory but requires you to do some more work.

Comment: You can always check the apps IPA so you can see how they slice there resources =)!

Comment: How can i see the IPA of an app in the appstore?

Comment: `~/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications`. Then select the IPA you want to decode, duplicate it, change it's extension to `zip`. Unzip it.